# Angular reactive form invalid after pressing back button

Tags: angular, forms, validation, back, reactive

I got an Angular Reactive Form working well except when I fill all the required fields and I press Chrome's back button (after submitting it or not) and go back to the form page again. My form is still filled but I can't submit the form again. I guess it's because the form validation is invalid, I have to re fill every field in order to press the submit button again.

How can I force the re validation of the form so I don't have to erase and type everything again?

```
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    checkbox: [false],
    checkbox_cgv: [false, Validators.requiredTrue],
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    email:['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    phoneNumber:['', Validators.required],
    billing: this.fb.group({
      address1: ['', Validators.required],
      address2: [''],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      zip: ['', Validators.required]
    }),
    shipping: this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      address1: ['', Validators.required],
      address2: [''],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      zip: ['', Validators.required]
    }),
  });
```

Part of the html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p class="form-row form-left">
          <span class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName" required>
          </span>
        </p>
        <p class="form-row form-right">
          <span class="input-wrapper">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName" required>
          </span>
        </p>
...

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary order-btn" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Order</button>
```

Comment: i'm experiencing a similar issue. the form values in the form group are empty/default values even though the native elements have values populated by the browser. i am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the form on either `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit` but make sure this reset come after your form init

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  //reset form controls
  this.profileForm.reset();

  //reset validators, explicitly
  this.accountForm.setErrors(null)

}
```

if reseting the whole form doesn't affect the nested groups/arrays target them as `this.profileForm.controls['billing'].reset();`

Comment: thanks for your reply but this doesn't work. It's weird because if I do this `this.profileForm.reset({ firstName: 'ok', lastName: ''});` in ngAfterViewInit, it'll work the first time I load the page but not if I press back button

Comment: You don't have to call every control in `reset()`, and going back and return again, will definitely fire the `ngOnInit` hook.

Comment: I know I did it because `reset()` did nothing on `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Same issue, with our Angular 6 app

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try using

```
profileForm.resetForm()
```

Comment: `this.profileForm.resetForm is not a function` I also came accross this I think it's related by I don't know how I can fix it then https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26829

Answer (score 0):

I've created an angular directive to fix the issue if it's caused by the form not reflecting the values set by the browser's autofilling, which was the issue in my case. I've written it to support `FormGroup`s only, but it can be adapted to your use case.

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
    // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/directive-selector
    selector: '[formControlName]',
    standalone: true,
})
export class FormAutofillSyncDirective implements OnInit {

    private readonly element: Element;

    constructor(
        private readonly control: NgControl,
        elementRef: ElementRef,
    ) {
        this.element = elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.syncValue();
        });
    }

    private syncValue(): void {
        if ((this.element instanceof HTMLInputElement || this.element instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) && this.element.value != this.control.value) {
            this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
        } else if (this.element instanceof HTMLSelectElement && this.element.value != this.control.value) {
            this.element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, import it in the component that includes your form.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormAutofillSyncDirective],
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form.component.scss'
})
```